# How to intercept url loads in WebView (android)?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a WebView in which I load a page with a custom link (like app://action). I registered the url schemes in the manifest file and when I click on the link, the onResume() method of my  Activity is called with the correct data and it works OK.

My problem is that the WebView still try to load the link and my WebView ends up to show a "Web page unavailable" message. I don't want that.

How can I prevent the WebView to load the url?

Here's my code :

```
WebView banner = ...
banner.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.startsWith("app://")) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url), getContext(), Main.class);
            //startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}

banner.loadUrl("url_to_the_banner");
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading instead.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    // handle by yourself
    return true; 
}
```

[WebViewClient Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))

**Updates:** Method [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) is deprecated in API level 24. Use [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) instead.

Comment: if the tap in Webview is a link to custom URL, (like myurl://parameters), its not getting called. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

But it must return false otherwise, so:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    if(url.startsWith(myString){
        // handle by yourself
        return true;
    } 
    // ...
    return false;
}
```