# How can I use google chrome as a reference in android studio?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, google-chrome-extension

I don't know if this is possible or not but I was wondering. Is it possible to reference google chrome (app) in android studio? I was thinking about making an app that reference the google chrome app and have the app display the current url open in chrome, have else if statements for the url to change in chrome and maybe have show text of what url is being display in chrome in my app. I have been doing research and couldn't find any on this but found out there is ways to develop things in google chrome like [custom tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs), [Homescreen](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) and etc.

So, I thought maybe I would post my question here and see if anyone can help me or tell me if my request is possible?

Thank you in advance for the advice!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to open URLs in a specific browser.

But it's frowned upon because it'll most likely throw an `ActivityNotFoundException` exception if the target application is not installed for some reason.

You're better off giving the user the option to choose which browser they'd like to open the URL in.

An example of how to open a URL is as follows:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: (Passer) Thank for the reply.  I have research that URLs could be done with an app in android studio but is it possible to do else if or if statements using chrome? Like for example if I made any app that did a if statement to check the current url in chrome like "url=http://stackoverflow.com/" is true then the app would toast the message "development site".  How would I be able to do this, if possible?

Comment: I'm having trouble fully understanding what you're trying to achieve. But from what I can tell, Chrome doesn't allow another external app to control how it opens URLs that easily.
If you need fine-grained controls over how URLs are opened, you may use your own custom `WebView`, which is basically a slimmed down version of Chrome and then override the [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760310/how-to-intercept-url-loads-in-webview-android) method.

Comment: (Passer) Thank for the reply. Sorry about the misunderstanding information. Let me try to explain it better. I'm trying to take a URL from chrome and have my app check the URL. If the URL matches a URL I have in a if statement (which I'm trying to figure out would have it would equal the web address of chrome) then it would display a message or change the URL to another address in chrome. It something like that but I trying to think of an example. I really hope this helps you.

Comment: OK, that's much clearer. I'm sorry, but I don't think that's something Chrome itself would/should allow external apps to do (that's a lot of power to give to another app e.g. a malicious app can use this to spy on a user's browsing habit etc.)

The closest thing to being able to view the list of open tabs in Chrome is if you connect to your device via ADB, open chrome and then navigate to `chrome://inspect/#devices` on your device.

Comment: Ok, Passer. So, there is no way to do an extension like this on the google chrome app? because I want to make a app that is like an smart internet filter that would block and change url address around if the user went to the wrong address but it would made sense if google don't want this idea for the app and only wanted it for google chrome (Desktop).

Comment: I'm not a google app extension developer. So I wouldn't be able to say without having to do some digging around through their APIs. That being said, I'm pretty sure there's a way to trigger an extension on each page load, I'm just not sure if it can also be triggered if no page is actually loaded (e.g. Gateway Timeouts due to wrong URLs/domain names). That's something you'll probably have to look into.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you for your help and time (Passer)