# Webview - Open links in external browser?

Tags: android, browser, webview

Can anyone help me in opening specific link in External browser or other android app?

For Example if URL matches **whatsapp://** then it should open link in WhatsApp app and if WhatsApp is not installed then it should open **https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp** in android browser.

FYI: I am using https://github.com/SurfEdge/flarum-mobile-android to create Web View App for my Forum website.

My Android code looks like:

```
package com.example.example;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener{

public AdvancedWebView webView;
private ProgressBar mPbar = null;

private static final String  url = "https://example.com/";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mPbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loader);

    webView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.newWeb);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.setListener(this, this);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            AdvancedWebView newWebView = new AdvancedWebView(MainActivity.this);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            return true;
        }
    });

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    } else {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    mPbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    mPbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp");
            final Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            @SuppressWarnings({"NewApi", "deprecation"})
            final int newDocumentFlag = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) ? Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT : Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET;
            goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | newDocumentFlag | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

        try {
            startActivity(goToMarket);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp")));
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

    });


    webView.setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    webView.setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(true);
    webView.setCookiesEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    webView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    webView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    webView.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    webView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!webView.onBackPressed()) { return; }
    super.onBackPressed();
}


@Override
public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) {

}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(String url) {

}

@Override
public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

}

@Override
public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) {

}

@Override
public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) {

}
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error:(86, 11) error: cannot find symbol class Uri
Error:(86, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable Uri
Error:(94, 22) error: cannot find symbol class ActivityNotFoundException
Error:(95, 62) error: cannot find symbol variable Uri
```

P.S: I am not an Android Developer

Comment: this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760310/how-to-intercept-url-loads-in-webview-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, determine if the url has the specified prefix, and then open the Whatsapp listing on Play Store, or if the Play Store is not installed, open it inside browser :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        mPbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        mPbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
            // create an intent for Play Store
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp");
            final Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            @SuppressWarnings({"NewApi", "deprecation"})
            final int newDocumentFlag = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) ? Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT : Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET;
            goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | newDocumentFlag | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

            try {
                // open Whatsapp listing in Play Store app
                startActivity(goToMarket);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                // open Whatsapp listing in browser
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp")));
            }

            return true;
        }

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

});
```

**EDIT**

Add this lines to the top of the file to import the necessary classes :

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.net.Uri;
```

Comment: Error: Cannot find class Uri and ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: Please edit your question and include the stack trace

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: Then import the mentions classes

Comment: I am extremely sorry but what does that mean?