# error with swipe to refresh layout

Tags: android

Thanks for having a look at my question.
I am developing an android app which is basically a webview based app. I have used navigation drawer in this app with webview. I have used swipe to refresh layout to refresh my webpage but i am facing some issues with it.

I have total 9 pages in this app. (1) Home (2) Result (3)Exam Schedule (4) Seating Arrangement (5) Candidate List (6) Old Question Papers (7) Syllabus (8) Anti Ragging (9) About.

My issue with this code:-
Suppose i am on Page (5) which is Candidate List and i swiped down to refresh the page (5) but when refresh gets finished, it takes me to the page (1) which is home page. I want to stay on the page (5) even after i refresh the page. I don't know why it is happening and what is wrong in my code. Please help me to solve this issue.

This video can elaborate my issue more efficiently :-
(Have a look on the video. It can explain my issue completely.)
http://www.mediafire.com/file/0w4l8s4xvarrxdx/Hand.mp4

Link to the APK file :-
http://www.mediafire.com/file/l1lxobs43f4c4tj/Gujarat_University%5B1%5D.apk

Please have a look at my source code :-

1) navigation.java

```
package com.anstrontech.gujaratuniversity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class navigation extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private AdView mAdView;

    final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                LoadWeb();
            }
        });
        LoadWeb();

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-5340020809562805~5856898353");


    }

    public void LoadWeb(){
        //improve webView performance

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.gujaratuniversity.ac.in/web/");
        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

        });
    }

    boolean twice;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "click");
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else if (twice == true){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            twice = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "twice: " + twice);

            Toast.makeText(navigation.this, "Press BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    twice = false;
                    Log.d(TAG, "twice: " + twice);
                }
            }, 3000);
            twice = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.gujaratuniversity.ac.in/web/");
            setTitle("Home");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_result) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://result.gujaratuniversity.ac.in/");
            setTitle("Result");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_examschedule) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.gujaratuniversity.ac.in/web/custom/student/examination-schedule");
            setTitle("Exam Schedule");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_seatingarrangement) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.gujaratuniversity.ac.in/web/custom/student/seating-arrangement");
            setTitle("Seating Arrangement");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_candidate) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.gujaratuniversity.ac.in/web/custom/student/candidate-list");
            setTitle("Candidate List");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_oldquestionpapers) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://sampada.inflibnet.ac.in/");
            setTitle("Old Question Papers");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_syllabus) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.gujaratuniversity.ac.in/web/custom/student/syllabus");
            setTitle("Syllabus");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_antiragging) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.gujaratuniversity.ac.in/web/custom/pdfs/anti-ragging");
            setTitle("Anti Ragging");
        }  else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.gujaratuniversity.ac.in/web/page/overview");
            setTitle("About");
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

2) content_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.anstrontech.gujaratuniversity.navigation"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_navigation">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5340020809562805/5619372430">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        </WebView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

3) AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.anstrontech.gujaratuniversity">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Gujarat University"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".navigation"
            android:label="Gujarat University"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Link to my Complete App Source Code:-
http://www.mediafire.com/file/lwm1qj415dclytd/GujaratUniversityN.zip

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening is because when you swipe down to refresh, `LoadWeb()` is called. In `LoadWeb()`, your `WebView` is then commanded to load `http://www.gujaratuniversity.ac.in/web/` which of course results in you seeing the home page.

Comment: Hmm. Yes you are right. Can you tell me that what should i do now. I really don't know that what should i do.

Comment: Override the url handling. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760310/how-to-intercept-url-loads-in-webview-android